# Creating custom menus in Applications-menu tab in CentOS7 GNOME

Tags: centos, gnome3

I have created a .menu file in `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/`, created .directory file in `/usr/share/desktop-directories/` and the various .desktop files i want to be in my custom menu under `/usr/share/applications` with a custom Categories extension `Categories=X-nameofcategory` yet still no menu appearing in my applications menu.

I am wondering if there is a step i am missing, i am not using alacarte because there are multiple applications that i need to create and alacarte is very manual, having to add directory paths for each icon, executable and there is no drag/drop method either. I had assumed there was a standard way to do this and have followed the steps that freedesktop describes but i am still at a loss. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a good tuto somewhere about creating menu in different distros?

Comment: @Quidam apologies for the late response but as far as I know, any Desktop Environment that uses the FreeDesktop should have similar setups. Try to peel away from the Distro and focus on the Desktop Environment you are working with, like GNOME, or Unity, or MATE, KDE etc. Then go to the distro specifics. I don't have any good tuts as i had to figure this out on my own!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one seems to know or wasn't able to answer so i'll throw up the solution I found!

There are 3 locations you should be concerned with:

- `/usr/share/desktop-directories`
- `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged`
- `/usr/share/applications`

Bear in mind the last location is system-wide specific, if you want it just for your user, use: `~/.local/share/applications`

Firstly we:

1. Create a file called `APPNAME.menu` (substitute `APPNAME` for whatever you want to call it) in the folder location `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged`
2. Input these contents:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd">
<Menu>
<Name>Applications</Name> <!-- This is necessary for your directory to appear in the applications drop down -->
<Menu> <!--app -->
<Name>app</Name>
<Directory>APPNAME.directory</Directory>
<Include>
<Category>APPNAME</Category>
</Include>
</Menu> <!-- End app -->
</Menu> <!-- End Applications -->
```

3. Save the file and create another file called `APPNAME.directory` in the folder location ( it should be the same name specified in the `.menu` file) 
   `/usr/share/desktop-directories` with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Directory
Name=AppName
Icon=/path/to/icon`
```

**Note** the `.directory` filename should be exactly the same as the `.directory` name you entered in the `.menu` file above.

4. Create a standard `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` or  `/usr/share/applications` with these contents (substituting for your own program of course and the `Categories=`line **MUST BE** the same as the name you gave the `.directory` file eariler)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/executable.sh
Name=ApplicationToRun
Icon=/path/to/icon
Categories=APPNAME
Comment=Comment for users
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a pretty good tuto, and the only one I've found so far about creating menus.

Comment: I want to create a new category, so no executable file, how to do that? And how to link apps to this category?